# How to save values from a dataframe as a string where condition is met?

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

I have a .csv file that looks a bit like this:

```
ID | Cancelled
---|----------
1  | N
2  | Y
3  | N
4  | N
5  | Y
```

I want to use Python to save the cancelled IDs to a variable as a string with this format:

```
('2','5')
```

It needs to be in this format because the variable will be used later on in a bit of SQL nested within the same Python script.

Does anyone know how to do this please? I'm able to get a dataframe that holds the relevant rows using the code below, but I don't know how to strip this down to just the ID column and convert the IDs into the correct format.

```
V_test1 = pd.read_csv("myfile.csv")
V_test2 = V_test1[V_test1['Cancelled'] == 'Y']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If ID is index then use:

```
out=tuple('000'+V_test1.loc[(V_test1['Cancelled']=='Y')].index.astype(str))
```

Else use:

```
out=tuple('000'+V_test1.loc[(V_test1['Cancelled']=='Y'),'ID'].astype(str))
```

Output:

```
print(out)
>>>
 ('0002','0005')
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful! One additional question though - is it possible to tweak the output to add leading zeroes, e.g. ('0002','0005')?

Comment: updated answer...Kindly have a look ***:)***

Comment: btw If you found this answer helpful then try considering accepting this answer....Thank you ***:)***

Comment: Sorry, I just thought of something - this doesn't work if there is only a single cancelled ID in the list, because the tuple then ends in a comma, which breaks the SQL code. My understanding is that the trailing comma is mandatory in single-value tuples; is this correct? And if so, do you know if there is another way to get the required result that will also work if there is only a single cancelled ID please?

Comment: My understanding is that the trailing comma is mandatory in single-value tuples; is this correct?: yes it is correct for example if you print `type(('hello'))` you will get  `str` but if you print `type(('hello',))` you will get `tuple` the same applies in your case if you don't put `,` for example `('0002')` is considered as string whereas `('0002',)` is considered as tuple